# Can someone identify this babel from visual studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

[image: unknown babel]

This image came from a class diagram and it was in the property section if that information helps

Comment: What is a "babel" in this context?

Comment: @John Saunders - I'm pretty sure he just means non-sense.

Comment: A babal is what the images are called in visual studios. they represent controls, properties, methods, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only seen that in the Data designer of the Entity Framework, not the Class Diagram.

In the EF Designer, it means "Complex Type", also known as "Value Type", because it doesn't have a key of its own.  You can see it in the picture here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/28/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-2-complex-types-deferred-loading-and-explicit-loading.aspx

Click on the picture to make it bigger.